# Why is the graph of $\sin(y)=x$ different from the graph of $y=\sin^{-1}(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Why is the graph of $\sin(y)=x$ different from the graph of $y=\sin^{-1}(x)$? Aren't they just the same thing but in the latter y is written in terms of x?

[image]

Comment: The domain and range are part of the definition of a function. If the domain and range differ, their graphs will differ. This is true in general including this case.

Comment: So sin(y)=x isn't considered a function but rather an equation?

Comment: It is a function. So is $\arcsin$. They just have different domains and ranges. That's why they have different graphs.

Comment: But sin(y)=x doesn't pass the vertical line test.

Comment: Don't let the $y$ and $x$ confuse you. They're arbitrary names and replacing one with the other doesn't actually change anything. The $y$ should be the horizontal axis and the $x$ the vertical as you're written it.

Comment: So why did Quanto (the answer right under yours) say it isn't a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the explicit function has the range

$$y=\sin^{-1}(x)\in (-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$$

while the implicit function below has quite different range

$$\sin(y)=x,\>\>\>\>\>y\in(-\infty,\infty)
$$

Comment: $\arcsin x$ belongs to the *closed* interval.

Comment: So by just making y stand alone I kind of stated that the equation I'm about to write must be a function, and that its demain must be that it would pass the vertical line test, did I get this right? But if I write it in an implicit form it's okay to for it to not be a function..... Why did you call it implicit *function* then?

Comment: Yeah I get this part but I mean why did you call it a *function* when its graph shows it isn't?

Comment: @Manar - you’re right. $\sin y= x$ is not a function. I loosely used the term

Answer (score 1):

They aren't the same thing, because $y=\arcsin x$ (or $\sin^{-1}x$, as you write it), is defined, not only by $\sin y=x$, but also by the constraint  $-\frac\pi2\le y\le\frac\pi 2$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the definition of $\arcsin(x)$. In particular, the range of $\arcsin(x)$ is the closed interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. So when you look at $\arcsin(0)$, it is the value $x$ in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ such that $\sin(x) = 0$, namely $x=0$. However, the solution set to $\sin(y)=0$ is every number $y$ such that $\sin(y)=0$, for which there are infinitely many such $y$. This explains why your graph of $\sin(y)=0$ has infinitely many horizontal lines. Note here that I am using the notation $\arcsin(x)$ to denote the inverse sine function which you denote as $\sin^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, fixed.